# Simulate rows with columns without tables

Tags: html, css

I have reasons for not wanting to use the html markup for a table but I am trying to create a structure of rows, each with three columns.

Here is what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/3rpu0hb5/5/

HTML

```
  <div id="row">
    <div id="name">
        <h4>First Col</h4>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="detail">
        <h4>Middle Col</h4>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="location">
        <h4>Right Col</h4>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.row .name {width: 200px; float:left;}
.row .detail {width: 200px; float:left;}
.row .location {width: 200px; float:left;}
```

What is missing here, because they still display below each other?

Comment: There is only one thing that looks like a row in the markup, and the use of `id` (instead of `class`) suggests that it is really meant to be the only row. So what is the actual markup? If there are several “rows”, do they appear inside a container (which would then be a “table”)?

Comment: They do not appear in a table container, no, should they?

Comment: If the appear in a container, and if each “row” is an element, it is easy to set up tabular layout using CSS table properties, with `display: table` and friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used a class selector `.row` instead of an id selector `#row`

```
#row div {width: 200px; float:left;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3rpu0hb5/11/

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` trick:

```
#row{display:table;}
.disTableCell{display:table-cell;width: 200px;}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3rpu0hb5/8/)

Comment: This requires added markup, which is not present in the question or in the answer, just in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Your row is id not class , so replace '.' => '#'

```
#row #name {width: 200px; float:left;}
#row #detail {width: 200px; float:left;}
#row #location {width: 200px; float:left;}
```